# Обнуление shared_pointer

Tags: c++, boost

Есть класс

```
class Camera {
public:
    void initCamera();
    void destroyCamera();
    static boost::shared_ptr<Camera> createCamera();
    ~Camera();
private:
    Camera();
    static boost::shared_ptr<Camera> cameraInstance;
};
```

1. При компиляции в `Camera.cpp` на строке:

   ```
   boost::shared_ptr<Camera> Camera::cameraInstance = NULL;
   ```

   выдаётся ошибка:

   > ошибка error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать int в boost::shared_ptr
2. В деструкторе на строке

   ```
   cameraInstance = NULL;
   ```

   Выдаётся ошибка:

   > error C2679: бинарный '=': не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа 'int' (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Как исправить?

Comment: и причем здесь sharepoint?

Comment: посмотрел на код, похоже, что пытаетесь сделать ручное управление shared_ptr. То, что там уже есть, заворачивается ещё в одно:).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cameraInstance.reset()`

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `nullptr` вместо `NULL`. Это более правильный способ записать нулевой указатель, и у shared_ptr есть специальный конструктор принимающий `std::nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>boost::shared_ptr<Camera> Camera::cameraInstance = NULL;
```

при инициализации шаред поинтера, его указатель уже будет ссылаться в "ничто".
Нет смысла его нулить, оператора '=' для инта там действительно нет.

Обнулить поинтер можно через метод `reset()`, но правильнее всего, 
предварительно вызвать конструктор того объекта который в поинтере содержиться.